# Best way to perform calculations on a list/tuple in Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I wrote this program that will tell you the two <s>multiples</s> factors of your input. Ex. if I were to input 35 (a semiprime), the program would print 5 and 7, which are the two prime numbers that multiply to 35.

But I am wondering if there is a more concise or pythonic way to iterate through this tuple so I wouldn't have to code all those "elif" statements you see below.

Also it would be great if I didn't need to rely on any external libraries.

```
# multiples of semiprimes 4 - 49
tuple1 = ( 2, 3, 5, 7 )

# tuple 1 calculations
while True:

        try:
                semiprime = int(input('Enter Semiprime: '))

        except ValueError:
                print('INPUT MUST BE AN INTEGER')
                continue

        # index 0 - 3
        if (tuple1[0]) * (tuple1[0]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[0]), (tuple1[0]))

        elif (tuple1[0]) * (tuple1[1]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[0]), (tuple1[1]))

        elif (tuple1[0]) * (tuple1[2]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[0]), (tuple1[2]))

        elif (tuple1[0]) * (tuple1[3]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[0]), (tuple1[3]))

        # index 1 - 3
        elif (tuple1[1]) * (tuple1[0]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[1]), (tuple1[0]))

        elif (tuple1[1]) * (tuple1[1]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[1]), (tuple1[1]))

        elif (tuple1[1]) * (tuple1[2]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[1]), (tuple1[2]))

        elif (tuple1[1]) * (tuple1[3]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[1]), (tuple1[3]))

        # index 2 - 3
        elif (tuple1[2]) * (tuple1[0]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[2]), (tuple1[0]))

        elif (tuple1[2]) * (tuple1[1]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[2]), (tuple1[1]))

        elif (tuple1[2]) * (tuple1[2]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[2]), (tuple1[2]))

        elif (tuple1[2]) * (tuple1[3]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[2]), (tuple1[3]))

        #index 3 - 3
        elif (tuple1[3]) * (tuple1[0]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[3]), (tuple1[0]))

        elif (tuple1[3]) * (tuple1[1]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[3]), (tuple1[1]))

        elif (tuple1[3]) * (tuple1[2]) == semiprime:
                print((tuple1[3]), (tuple1[2]))
```

Comment: [`itertools.combinations(tuple1, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: @jedwards 's way is wisdom! A nested for loop seems ok too.

Comment: instead of limiting yourself to a precalculate list of prime numbers, you can calculate the prime factorization of the given number, using either a prime checking function or a prime generating one like the Sieve of Eratostenes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hinted at this in my comment, but realized just the link to the function docs may not be enough.

Here's how you could write your code using [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

# multiples of semiprimes 4 - 49
tuple1 = ( 2, 3, 5, 7 )

# tuple 1 calculations
while True:

    try:
        semiprime = int(input('Enter Semiprime: '))

    except ValueError:
        print('INPUT MUST BE AN INTEGER')
        continue

    for (x,y) in combinations_with_replacement(tuple1, 2):
        if x * y == semiprime:
            print(x,y)
```

Much nicer, IMO :)

**Edit**: A previous version used [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) which wouldn't yield (x,y) pairs with the same value (e.g. `(x,y) = (2,2)` would never happen).  `combinations_with_replacement` allows for duplicates.  Thanks to @Copperfield for pointing this out.

Comment: in this case I think that `combinations_with_replacement` is the correct one because the OP also check for elements in the same position

Comment: @Copperfield you're right, they do -- editing it in.

Comment: @jedwards much nicer, thanks! But in the for loop, what is the '2' for in the functions arguments?

Comment: @miro.kh the second argument of `combinations_with_replacement`, `2` in this case, is the desire size of each group of results you get from that, with 2 you get `(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 7), (3, 3), ...` with 3 you get `(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 5), (2, 2, 7), (2, 3, 3), ...` etc

Comment: @miro.kh the length of the combination / number of elements you want to be yielded.

Answer (score 1):

While jedwards demonstrates the most Pythonic approach - using the `itertools` library which you will come to know and love- here is the more "classic" approach using for-loops for the pattern you want. I bring it up because as a programming beginner, it is important to know this basic, imperative idiom:

```
>>> tuple1 = (2,3,5,7)
>>> for i in range(len(tuple1)):
...   for j in range(i+1, len(tuple1)):
...     print(tuple1[i], tuple1[j])
... 
2 3
2 5
2 7
3 5
3 7
5 7
>>>
```

Thus, your code would be shortened to:

```
for i in range(len(tuple1)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(tuple1)):
        if tuple1[i] * tuple1[j] == semiprime
            print(tuple1[i], tuple1[j])
```

Comment: I don't hate the nested loop, but I think iterating over the tuple (e.g. `for e1 in tuple1: for e2 in tuple1: ...`) might be better

Comment: @jedwards But then you would get the product, not every unique combination. You could avoid that by using a slice (or better yet,`islice`) and iterating over the tuple, but I didn't want to bring that up since it is the pattern that matters anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Even though @**jedwards** solution is great, (*as well as concise/pythonic*); one other possible solution:

```
def prime_multiples(l,t ):  
    for i in l:  # Iterate over our list.
        for j in t:  # Iterate over the tuple of prime factors.
            #  We check to see that we can divide without a remainder with our factor,
            #  then check to see if that factor exists in our tuple.
            if i%j == 0 and i/j in t:
                print "Prime factors: {} * {} = {}".format(j, i/j, i)
                break  # We could go not break to print out more options.
```

**Sample output:**

```
l = [4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49]
t = ( 2, 3, 5, 7 )
prime_multiples(l, t)
>>> Prime factors: 2 * 2 = 4
... Prime factors: 2 * 3 = 6
... Prime factors: 3 * 3 = 9
... Prime factors: 2 * 5 = 10
... Prime factors: 2 * 7 = 14
... Prime factors: 3 * 5 = 15
... Prime factors: 3 * 7 = 21
... Prime factors: 5 * 5 = 25
... Prime factors: 5 * 7 = 35
... Prime factors: 7 * 7 = 49
```